E80 error on nest 3rd generation thermostat
I got an e80 error on my 3rd generation nest thermostat. I live in Hawaii so I only use the air conditioner. The device was working and spinning the fan blades yesterday. But today the error showed and the blades are not spinning. How do I fix it ? What could be wrong ?

I would look at the directions that came with the thermostat for information as to what that error code means. I would also contact the manufacturer for advice.

No power to Y1 wire detected (cold weather shutoff).

You'll get this code if your air conditioner has tripped a safety cut-out switch that prevents your air conditioner from turning on in very cold weather, or your system might need maintenance.

Either you have a bad connection on your Y1 wire, or your system has faulted and interrupted the connection to get you to service it. A common reason for this sort of failure is a failed condensate pump or blocked drip pan. When the air conditioner is running, it causes water to condense out of the air on the cool side, i.e. on the air handler inside the house. That condensate has to go somewhere, either out of a drain or out a pump. If the pump is not working or the drain is plugged, there's a float switch which turns on and interrupts the power to your thermostat to stop the system from continuing to run and flood your home. Check to make sure the drain is clear and the condensate pump is working properly, then try resetting the entire system by switching power off and on. If it doesn't come back to life, or the drains are all clear, it's going to need more extensive service. At that point we'll need a whole lot more information to help, and it's likely time for a professional if you're not comfortable working on HVAC systems.
